# How does the mysql max_connections variable get enforced?

Tags: mysql

In mysql, how does the max_connections variable get enforced? Namely, my question is--when the maximum number of connections is reached--(a) are new connections refused, or (b) will mysql first try to close old connections and/or idle connections to accommodate the new ones?

Comment: I haven't tested, but refusing new connections seems like the most likely scenario.

Comment: What's the most likely scenario?

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for [`max_connections`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections), and for the [Too Many Connections error](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html).

Considering MySQL has to return this error code to the clients, that means it actually `accept()`s the connection, but delivers that error, and closes the connection.

Comment: The documentation for "max_connections" says:

The maximum permitted number of simultaneous client connections. By default, this is 151. See Section B.5.2.7, “Too many connections”, for more information.

Increasing this value increases the number of file descriptors that mysqld requires. See Section 8.4.3.1, “How MySQL Opens and Closes Tables”, for comments on file descriptor limits.

I can't figure out the answer to the question from that.

The other link isn't working.

Comment: @Scott Fixed the link. Sorry about that. It should be obvious though, that if a client gets a "Too Many Connections" error, that the server was the one who sent that error. Which means the server accepted the connectinon, send the error, and then sent the client on its way.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still not confident about whether or not mysql will attempt to close idle connections before returning a too many connections error to a new person trying to connect.

Comment: You should be able to test this pretty easily, by setting `max_connections` to something like 1, opening a connection, letting it idle, and trying to open a new one. I would be very surprised if it forcefully closed an already-open connection.